# Why is this if statment failing with two arguments

Tags: php

Im including a chunk of html with some echo statements included based on a an if statement.

```
<?
    if($rows['business_type'] !== "Hotel" || "Bed & Breakfast")
    {
?>


    <div id="mini_titles"><h2>Opening times</h2></div>

    <div id="complete_info_wrapper">
            <div id="complete_info_title"><p>Monday</p></div>
            <div id="complete_info_details_opening">
               <p>
<?php echo $rows1['opening_monday_from']; ?> - 
<?php echo $rows1['opening_monday_to']; ?>
               </p>
           </div>
    </div>
    <div id="complete_info_wrapper">
        <div id="complete_info_title"><p>Tuesday</p></div>
        <div id="complete_info_details_opening">
            <p>
<?php echo $rows1['opening_tuesday_from']; ?> - 
<?php echo $rows1['opening_tuesday_to']; ?>
            </p>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div id="complete_info_wrapper">
            <div id="complete_info_title"><p>Wednesday</p></div>
            <div id="complete_info_details_opening">
               <p>
<?php echo $rows1['opening_wednesday_from']; ?> - 
<?php echo $rows1['opening_wednesday_to']; ?>
               </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="complete_info_wrapper">
            <div id="complete_info_title"><p>Thursday</p></div>
            <div id="complete_info_details_opening">
                <p>
<?php echo $rows1['opening_thursday_from']; ?> - 
<?php echo $rows1['opening_thursday_to']; ?>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="complete_info_wrapper">
            <div id="complete_info_title"><p>Friday</p></div>
            <div id="complete_info_details_opening">
               <p>
<?php echo $rows1['opening_friday_from']; ?> - 
<?php echo $rows1['opening_friday_to']; ?>
               </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="complete_info_wrapper">
            <div id="complete_info_title"><p>Saturday</p></div>
            <div id="complete_info_details_opening">
                <p>
<?php echo $rows1['opening_saturday_from']; ?> - 
<?php echo $rows1['opening_saturday_to']; ?>
                </p>
           </div>
        </div>

        <div id="complete_info_wrapper">
            <div id="complete_info_title"><p>Sunday</p></div>
            <div id="complete_info_details_opening">
                <p>
<?php echo $rows1['opening_sunday_from']; ?> - 
<?php echo $rows1['opening_monday_to']; ?>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php
    }

?>
```

The if statment works if I use only one ie:

```
if($rows['business_type'] !== "Hotel"){}
```

But as soon as i add `||`, `or`, `&&`, or `and` with the second it fails and shows regardless.

Im sure it something silly and simple im missing.

Help please and thank you.

Comment: You're not comparing `"Bed & Breakfast"` to anything.

Comment: `if($rows['business_type'] !== "Hotel" || $rows['business_type'] !== "Bed & Breakfast")`

Comment: if($rows['business_type'] !== "Hotel" || "Bed & Breakfast") if($rows['business_type'] != || $rows['business_type'] != "Bed & Breakfast")

Comment: I suggest to read again the syntactic basis of the language ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In that if condition if `$rows['business_type'] !== "Hotel"` is true then the condition will always be true. Because `if ("Bed & Breakfast")` is `true`. So `true || true` would be `true`.

It should be -

```
if($rows['business_type'] !== "Hotel" || $rows['business_type'] != "Bed & Breakfast")
```

Or you can do -

```
if (!in_array($rows['business_type'], array("Hotel", "Bed & Breakfast")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if($rows['business_type'] !== "Hotel" || $rows['business_type'] !== "Bed & Breakfast")
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because it has some typo:

Change

```
<?
if($rows['business_type'] !== "Hotel" || "Bed & Breakfast")
 // This //statement will always return true, because even if first condition 
// satisfies or not, 'Bed & Breakfast' will always return true (it is a 
//string which is not empty.
{
?>
// TRUE || TRUE --> TRUE
// FALSE || TRUE --> TRUE
// TRUE || FALSE --> TRUE
// FALSE || FALSE --> FALSE
```

to

```
<?
if($rows['business_type'] !== "Hotel" || $rows['business_type'] !== "Bed & Breakfast") // PUT YOUR CONDITION CORRECTLY.
{
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare against two values by this way. Use `in_array`:

```
if (!in_array($rows['business_type'], array("Hotel", "Bed & Breakfast"))) {...}
```

Or usign `||`

```
if ($rows['business_type'] !== "Hotel" || $rows['business_type'] !== "Bed & Breakfast") {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

"Bed & Breakfast" is a string not a comparison and it always returns `true`. so `x or true` always equals to `true`. that's the problem with your if statement. 
This might work as you expected:

```
if($rows['business_type'] !== "Hotel" || $rows['business_type'] !== "Bed & Breakfast")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try array method

```
if (in_array(array('Hotel', 'Bed'), $rows['business_type'])) {
    echo "'Bed' was found\n";
}
```